# Query to find the size of data in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column called `RawData` of datatype `Image` in my table. I need to find all rows where the size of that column is more than 1 MB.

It would be great if someone could help me with the query for this. I use SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `datalength(field)` to get size of data and then compare it.

Comment: `IMAGE` is deprecated since SQL Server 2005 - use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATALENGTH(RawData) > 1048576
```